# Calling private constructor of Class<T> from Class<U>

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++14, clang++

Below is a simplified version of code I have.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T> struct Foo {
  using Value = T;
  constexpr Foo() = delete;
  constexpr Foo(T v) : value(v) {}
  T value;
};

template <typename T> struct Vec {
  using Elem = Foo<T>;
  using Container = std::vector<Elem>;

  Vec() = delete;
  template <typename... Elems>
  Vec(Elem a, Elem b, Elems... rest)
      : elems_{a, b, rest...} {}

  void add(const Elem &e) { elems_.push_back(e); }

  template <typename F> auto map(const F &f) const;

private:
  Vec(Container &&c) : elems_(std::move(c)) {}
  Container elems_;
};

template <typename C>
template <typename F>
auto Vec<C>::map(const F &f) const {
  using ReturnedFoo = decltype(f(std::declval<typename Vec<C>::Elem>()));
  using ValueType = typename ReturnedFoo::Value;
  using Container = typename Vec<ValueType>::Container;
  Container mapped_elems;
  mapped_elems.reserve(elems_.size());
  std::transform(elems_.begin(), elems_.end(), std::back_inserter(mapped_elems),
                 f);
  return Vec<ValueType>{std::move(mapped_elems)};
}

Foo<int> mul2(Foo<int> x) {
    return Foo<int>{2 * x.value};
}
Foo<double> to_d(Foo<int> x) {
  return Foo<double>{static_cast<double>(x.value)};
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto f1 = Foo<int>(1);
  constexpr auto f2 = Foo<int>(2);
  constexpr auto f3 = Foo<int>(3);
  const auto v1 = Vec<int>{f1, f2, f3};
  const auto v2 = v1.map(mul2);
  // const auto v3 = v1.map(to_d); // call to private constructor from here
}
```

My class `Vec<T>` internally holds elements of type `Foo<T>` in `std::vector` and it always holds at least 2 elements.

I wrote  a `map` function that maps/tranforms every element and returns a new `Vec` object. Everything works fine for mapping functions which do not change a type of element (`F : (T) -> T`), like `mul2`. But general case (`F : (T) -> U`) doesn't work because there's a call to private constructor in class `Vec<U>` from `Vec<T>::map` function. Making this constructor public would make it possible to create `Vec` object with fewer than 2 elements so that's not what I want.

My first attempt of solving this problem was

```
  template <typename X> friend class Vec<X>;
```

but it seems it's not allowed. Here's clang++'s output:

```cpp
vec.cpp:23:14: error: partial specialization cannot be declared as a friend
      friend class Vec<X>;
```

Is there a way of making it work?
During writing this question I came up with an idea of rewriting the last line of map as:

```
  Vec<ValueType> result{mapped_elems[0], mapped_elems[1]};
  for (auto it = mapped_elems.begin() + 2 ; it != mapped_elems.end(); ++it) {
      result.add(*it);
  }
  return result;
```

But is there another way?

(Btw. I have clang 3.5.0 and g++ 4.9.2)

Comment: your friend declaration should be `template <typename X> friend struct Vec;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want any specialization of `Vec` to be a friend of the current `Vec<T>` instantiation, the friend declaration should be:

```
template <typename X> friend struct Vec;
//                                     ^ ok, plain identifier
```

instead of:

```
template <typename X> friend class Vec<X>;
//                                    ^~~ wrong!
```

§11.3 [class.friend]/p3:

> A friend declaration that does not declare a function shall have one of the following forms:
>
> ```
> friend elaborated-type-specifier ;
> friend simple-type-specifier ;
> friend typename-specifier ;
> ```
>
> [ *Note:* A friend declaration may be the *declaration* in a *template-declaration* (Clause 14, 14.5.4).— *end note* ]

The syntax you're currently using matches a declaration of a partial specialization of `Vec`, which is forbidden by §14.5.4 [temp.friend]/p8:

> Friend declarations shall not declare partial specializations.

Answer (score 2):

You just have the wrong `friend` syntax there:

```
template <typename U> friend struct Vec;
```